# How to use IcmpSendEcho2 with PIO_APC_ROUTINE?

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous, ping, icmp

I'm a c++ newbie and I'm trying to make a "ping tool" with [IcmpSendEcho2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366051%28v=vs.85%29) but I can't make it to work with APCs.

I'm running into this compiling error:

```
>error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
>warning C4191: 'type cast' : unsafe conversion from 'PIO_APC_ROUTINE (__cdecl *)(PVOID,PIO_STATUS_BLOCK,ULONG)' to 'PIO_APC_ROUTINE'
>          Calling this function through the result pointer may cause your program to fail
```

This is my APC declaration:

```
PIO_APC_ROUTINE GotIt(PVOID param, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, ULONG Reserved);
```

This is my APC definition:

```
PIO_APC_ROUTINE GotIt(PVOID param, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, ULONG Reserved)
{
    printf("GOT IT!\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

And this is how I make the IcmpSendEcho2:

```
DWORD dwRetVal = IcmpSendEcho2(hIcmpFile, NULL, (PIO_APC_ROUTINE) GotIt, NULL,
                     ipaddr, SendData, sizeof (SendData), NULL,
                     ReplyBuffer, ReplySize, 1000);
```

I thought '(PIO_APC_Rountine) GotIt' would do it, because I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/vcgeneral/thread/a2239425-fef4-45ed-b188-59a9c5f4a58e), but apparently I'm missing something.

If you need any additional information, let me know.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [don't cast callback functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx). **Ever**.

Second, `PIO_APC_ROUTINE` is declared as:

```
typedef
VOID
(NTAPI *PIO_APC_ROUTINE) (
    IN PVOID ApcContext,
    IN PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    IN ULONG Reserved
    );
```

So your `GotIt` function should be:

```
VOID NTAPI GotIt(
    IN PVOID ApcContext,
    IN PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    IN ULONG Reserved
);
```

`NTAPI` is `__stdcall`, not the default `__cdecl`, which is what the error message is telling you.

What you've done with this:

```
PIO_APC_ROUTINE GotIt(PVOID param, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, ULONG Reserved);
```

...is declare a function that **returns** a function pointer. This is not what you wanted.